# Javascript regex allow only specific characters

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I am using following code to allow only a-z, A-z, space, newline, tab.

But it doesn't allow `tab` key.

Here is my javascript code.

```
// Filter invalid characters in title
$('#p_title').keypress(function (e) {
        var regex = new RegExp("^[a-zA-Z0-9 \b\n\r\f\t\v]+$");
        var str = String.fromCharCode(!e.charCode ? e.which : e.charCode);
        if (regex.test(str)) {
                return true;
        }
        e.preventDefault();
        return false;
});
```

Comment: What do you mean by tab key?

Comment: The tab key which is just above "Caps Lock" key.

Answer (score 1):

You need to **double escape** all escape sequences for constructing `RegExp` object. However better to just use regex literal in your case:

```
var regex = /^[a-zA-Z0-9 \b\n\r\f\t\v]+$/;
```

Full code:

```
$('#p_title').keypress(function (e) {
        var regex = /^[a-zA-Z0-9 \b\n\r\f\t\v]+$/;
        var str = String.fromCharCode(!e.charCode ? e.which : e.charCode);
        if (regex.test(str)) {
           return true;
        }
        e.preventDefault();
        return false;
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Try use `.on` instead `.keypress`:

http://jsfiddle.net/z9wvfj1e/1/

```
// Filter invalid characters in title
$('#p_title').on('keydown', function (e) {
        if (e.keyCode >=37 && e.keyCode <=40) return true;
        var regex = new RegExp("^[a-zA-Z0-9 \b\n\r\f\t\v]+$");
        var str = String.fromCharCode(!e.charCode ? e.which : e.charCode);
        if (regex.test(str)) {
                console.log(e);
                return true;
        }
        e.preventDefault();
        return false;
});
```

Comment: Add simple check: `if (e.keyCode >=37 && e.keyCode <=40) return true;` [ http://jsfiddle.net/z9wvfj1e/3/ ]

Answer (score 1):

Something like this sounds like all you need:

```
$('#p_title').keypress(function (e) {
  return /[a-z]|\s|\r?\n|\t/i.test(String.fromCharCode(e.which));
});
```

I am doing a case-insensitive check for whether the character entered is a letter OR a space OR a newline OR a tab.

Furthermore, you don't need to check for `e.charCode` with jQuery because:

> The event.which property normalizes event.keyCode and event.charCode. It is recommended to watch event.which for keyboard key input.
>
> https://api.jquery.com/event.which/